# Python how to add a column in a CSV file from different file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 4 CSV files.
I am Able to merge all 4 of them but there is a problem with it.

This is one file named services.csv

```
ServiceID   Service
1   General Practitioner
2   Pathology
3   Radiology
4   Psychiatry
5   Chiropratic
```

and the other file ("I have named it test.csv")

```
ClinicServiceID ClinicID    ServiceID   Name    Suburb  State   Postcode    Email   Lat Lon
1   1   1   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    hurstville@myclinic.com.au  -33.975869  151.088939
2   1   2   Hurstville Clinic   Hurstville  NSW 1493    hurstville@myclinic.com.au  -33.975869  151.088939
3   2   1   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au  -33.867139  151.207114
4   2   2   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au  -33.867139  151.207114
5   2   3   Sydney Centre Clinic    Sydney  NSW 2000    sydney@myclinic.com.au  -33.867139  151.207114
```

Now I have to add Service Column from the Service.csv file according to the ServiceID in the test file.

I am able to merge all the files but I don't know how to perform the above operation.

```
Things that I Have to achieve:
1) Add Service column into the test.csv file
2) make the entries in the Service Column using the Service.csv file data.
```

Can anyone please help me. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `DataFrame`s with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new column after `ServiceID`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('services.csv') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

#get position of ServiceID column
pos = df2.columns.get_loc('ServiceID') + 1

df2.insert(pos, 'Service', df2['ServiceID'].map(df1.set_index('ServiceID')['Service']))
print (df2)
   ClinicServiceID  ClinicID  ServiceID               Service  \
0                1         1          1  General Practitioner   
1                2         1          2             Pathology   
2                3         2          1  General Practitioner   
3                4         2          2             Pathology   
4                5         2          3             Radiology   

                   Name      Suburb State  Postcode  \
0     Hurstville Clinic  Hurstville   NSW      1493   
1     Hurstville Clinic  Hurstville   NSW      1493   
2  Sydney Centre Clinic      Sydney   NSW      2000   
3  Sydney Centre Clinic      Sydney   NSW      2000   
4  Sydney Centre Clinic      Sydney   NSW      2000   

                        Email        Lat         Lon  
0  hurstville@myclinic.com.au -33.975869  151.088939  
1  hurstville@myclinic.com.au -33.975869  151.088939  
2      sydney@myclinic.com.au -33.867139  151.207114  
3      sydney@myclinic.com.au -33.867139  151.207114  
4      sydney@myclinic.com.au -33.867139  151.207114
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I need Service Column after Service ID also there's an extra column.

Comment: It worked Thanks. will index = false remove the extra column?

Comment: @Damian - Yes, if think `df.to_csv(file, index=False)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael,  in which case we will get the `IndexError`, could you explain

Comment: @pyd - Thank you for comment. I test it and find `min` is not necessary, because `pos = df2.columns.get_loc('Lon') + 1` working nice - add after last column.